# Move 7 segment display off board, how?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I bought a relay that has a 7 segment display on it.
It's placed "incorrectly" according to what I need so I want to move it off the board as simple as possible. (Because I'm not that good at this).

So lifting off the 7 segment I see this two rows of connections that I figure there might be a extension for.
Dream scenario would be a male part for this with a few inches of cable and then a female part again.
I understand that is probably not the case.

What are my options?
Do I have to unsolder the pins off the board and solder cables to each end of this row of pins?
It looks pretty hard to be honest.

[image]

Comment: There are flat cables and special press fit connectors for these to be inserted into an IC socket. But you need both a male and a female connector for flat cables with the pin count of the 7 segment display. I used the male connectors but I never saw the female ones. Good luck for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got machined pin socket on the board, you can buy a matching machined pin header, and piece of plated through matrix prototyping board and make a plug that fits that socket, and a socket that matches the pins on the LED display, then solder a piece of ribbon cable between them and plug it together.

I generally buy this stuff on Aliexpress (because price),
but here's some Sparkfun links,

machined pin header   https://www.sparkfun.com/products/117

machined pin socket   https://www.sparkfun.com/products/743

matrix proto board https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8808

ribbon cable https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10649

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. It has greatly improved my knowledge of these parts.